# How to get the total length of the Ltlngs from the polylineoptions in mapv2 in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, google-maps-android-api-2

I have PolylineOptions where I have some latitude and longitude saved in it. If I want to get the total length/distance of those locations in KM/miles then is there any default method from the api? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native API for that. You could sort your LatLngs and sum the distance between them with [Location.distanceTo(Location)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) or [Location.distanceBetween(double,double,double,double,float[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29), which are using the WGS84 ellipsoid. The result will be in meters.

Edit:

```
List<LatLng> latlngs = polylineOptions.getPoints();
int size = latlngs.size() - 1;
float[] results = new float[1];
float sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    Location.distanceBetween(
        latlangs.get(i).latitude, 
        latlangs.get(i).longitude,
        latlangs.get(i+1).latitude,
        latlangs.get(i+1).longitude,
        results);
    sum += results[0];
}
```

Comment: can you show me an exampe like I have a polylineoption with 3 LatLng where first item of this is the source and the last item of the polylineoption is the destination I want the total distance of the polyline path

Comment: I did the same, but I am not sure that is is correct or not? Is there any way to verify my results? btw thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Reyjohn Use Google Maps and create a route with your coordinates, then compare the results. That's the easiest way.